# Output data from list using search button python

Tags: python, list, search, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to create a search gui with a ListBox. It will output data to the Listbox if there is data in a list that matches the string that they input.

I am having an issue getting the data the matches to display to ListBox. All the data in the list is appearing. Pretty new to Python. Below is what I have to far.

Thanks

```
from tkinter import *


w = Tk()
liststuff = ["bob", "john", "theo", "bobby"]
l1 = Label(w, text='Name')
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

title_text = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(w, textvariable=title_text)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

list1 = Listbox(w, height=0, width=35)
list1.grid(row=1, rowspan=4, columnspan=2)

sb1 = Scrollbar(w)
sb1.grid(row=1, column=3)


def search_command():

    list1.delete(0, END)
    for x in liststuff:
        list1.insert(END, x)


list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)

b1 = Button(w, text="Search", width=12, command=search_command)
b1.grid(row=0, column=4)

w.mainloop()
```

Comment: it seams your problem is not `tkinter` but basics of Python. `if A in B` or `if A.startswith(B)`

Answer (score 0):

You need basics of Python

```
if "dylan" in "bob dylan":  # True

if "bob dylan".startswith("dylan"):  # False

if "dylan" in "Bob Dylan":  # False

if "dylan".lower() in "Bob Dylan".lower():  # True
```

Now you can search in list

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def search_command(event=None):

    # to compare lower case
    text = e1.get().lower()

    list1.delete(0, 'end')

    if text: # search only if text is not empty
        for word in liststuff:
            if word.lower().startswith(text):
                list1.insert('end', word)

# --- main ---

liststuff = ["bob", "john", "theo", "bobby"]

# GUI

root = tk.Tk()

l1 = tk.Label(root, text='Name')
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

title_text = tk.StringVar()

e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=title_text)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e1.bind('<KeyRelease>', search_command)

list1 = tk.Listbox(root, height=0, width=35)
list1.grid(row=1, rowspan=4, columnspan=2)

sb1 = tk.Scrollbar(root)
sb1.grid(row=1, column=3)

list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)

b1 = tk.Button(root, text="Search", width=12, command=search_command)
b1.grid(row=0, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

---

To search without `Button` you can bind `<KeyRelease>` to `Entry`

```
e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=title_text)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

e1.bind('<KeyRelease>', search_command)
```

and it will execute `search_command` after every key in `Entry`

But it will execute `search_command()` with one argument `event` which you have to receive

```
def search_command(event):
```

or if you want to use function with `bind` and with `command=` at the same time.

```
def search_command(event=None):
```